# What's the correct way to create a custom formatter for a comment?

Tags: 8, comments

I'd like to create a [custom formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter) for the field *Comments*. My goal is to display a custom comments section beside CKEditor (URL /node/xx/edit). Following [this article](https://www.webwash.net/how-to-create-a-custom-field-formatter-in-drupal-8/), I created my custom module:

*custom_comments/custom_comments.module*

```
function custom_comments_theme() {
  return [
    'custom_comment_formatter' => [
      'variables' => ['name' => NULL],
      'template'  => 'custom-comment-formatter',
    ],
  ];
}
```

*custom_comments/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/CustomCommentFormatter.php*

```
namespace Drupal\custom_comments\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase;

/**
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "custom_comment",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom Comment Formatter"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "comment"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class CustomCommentFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $name = $item->getName();
      $elements[$delta] = [
        '#theme' => 'custom_comment_formatter',
        '#name'   => $name,
      ];
    }

    return $elements;
  }

}
```

*custom_comments/templates/custom-comment-formatter.html.twig*

```
{{ name }}
```

I installed this module and then, just to test the display, I created a new content type "Special article" with a *Comments* field. In "Manage display", I changed format from *Comment list* to *Custom Comment Formatter*. However no comment names are displayed on the node page.

I noticed there is two different things: the list of comments and the comments themselves. Should I use two custom templates (one for the list, another for each comment)?

What's the correct way to display a custom list of comments?

Comment: Have you flushed caches? Have you installed the Devel sub-module Kint? Have you had any output from within `viewElements` when doing `ksm($name)`? Have you had any output from within your template when doing `{{ kint() }}`? What does Twig Debug give you? Is your template taken into account? And again: Have you flushed caches? Please **update your question** to clarify.

Comment: Are you trying to make comments appear on the node edit page? That'll require more than some custom templates to achieve.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong, yes. I created a [topic on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/3015240/) about the full feature. I have already been able to display a custom block on the node edit page but I am wondering about the way to bring the comments in it.

Comment: @Kwadz OK, I guess I don't really get the point of this given that commenting and editing are different processes and displaying all the many comments a node might have seems like a way to clutter up the edit page, but it should be quite simple to create a view of comments with the node ID as contextual filter and display that as a block.